# How to declare the backing bean's name only once in a JSF facelet?

Tags: java, jsf

After spending 2 hours debugging my webapp (JSF facelets with Primfaces and JSF ManagedBeans) it turned out that I missspelled the name of the backing bean (with a lengthy name) in one dataTable (unfortunately, I did not get any error message, there was just no data showing up in the table)

As I'm normally using one backing bean (controller) for my view, such errors could be reduced by declaring the name of the backing bean as a constant just once in the facelet (i.e. the xhtml file) and referring to this constant in the EL where methods on that bean are called. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Does `<c:set var="foo" value="#{lengthyBeanName}" />` fulfill your requirement? (you can then reference your bean parameters and methods with #{foo.param}

Comment: Set your project to development mode when developing. You'll likely get errors then in most cases

Comment: As an addition, if you are using JSF templating I often use `<ui:param name="ctrl" value="#{ctrlBeanName}" />`

Comment: If you're working on a team or with a company, I don't think what you're attempting is a good idea, because it's unconventional. When I'm looking for bean usages, I look for the beans by name. I don't want aliases.

Comment: Netbeans offers code completion for backing beans. If you're using Netbeans, just type Control > Space to open up a list of available backing beans. This will help prevent spelling errors.

Comment: If you just want a shorter, easier to type name for the backing bean, set it in the annotation using `@ManagedBean(name=)` or `@Named(name=)`.

Comment: Nonsense. Just do find and replace in all files. Eclipse even supports a regex based one and a preview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

both

```
<c:set var="foo" value="#{lengthyBeanName}" />
```

and

`<ui:param name="ctrl" value="#{ctrlBeanName}" /`>

did the trick. But it does of course not really solve the core problem (namely that some primefaces components as e.g. dataTable do not complain when a non-existing bean is uses to load the data/collection)